# ERC20: Why the specification uses 2 transactions for transferring token?

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

I was going through ERC20 lately and came across 2 level transfer protocol:

- `approve` - Allow receiver to debit `x` tokens in `n` transcations
- `transfer` - Transfer `y` tokens: `y` * `n` <= `x`

Why this was not implemented as 1 transaction, i.e. transfer `x` tokens to receiver wallet, as opposed to 2-level protocol (`allow` + `transfer`)? This leads to 2x usage of Eth gas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not quite like that. There are two different workflows.

1. An owner of tokens, A, can transfer his/her tokens to someone else's account using the `transfer` function. Only a single call is needed for this.

   Token owner A executes `transfer(B, n)`, then A's balance decreases by `n`, and B's balance increases by `n`.
2. In addition, the owner of tokens can also authorise someone else to transfer tokens from his/her account to any other account.  This requires two calls.

   Token owner A calls `approve(B, m)`.  B can now transfer up to `m` tokens out of A's account using the `transferFrom` function: `transferFrom(A,B,n)`, to move `n` tokens (<=`m`) to B's own account, or `transferFrom(A,C,n)` to move them from A's account to C's account.

So it all makes a kind of sense. I suspect the `approve`/`transferFrom` workflow isn't used a great deal, though.

Comment: Hi, I'm new in dapp. I tested this 'transfer' function on front end javascript dapp using web3 contract abi api. but there is additional parameter like '{from: accounts[3]}'. How this can be work? transferring anyone's token to any others

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion [for EIP20](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/20), `approve` and friends are used to enable another contract/account to transfer tokens while `transfer` is used by the owner to transfer tokens.

Suppose you have 10 ChazTokens and you wish to allow me to transfer 1 of them; you can `approve` my account to transfer a token and then I can use `transferFrom` to move one token at a time, whenever I want (you'd use `approveOnce` to let me do it only once). Note that in this case, there are two separate callers: you and me. This is why we use two functions here.

You can simply move your own tokens using the `transfer` function.